# Angular Material mat-table sticky header that has rowspan and colspan and then its position is shifted. How canI fix it?

Tags: angular, header, sticky, mat-table

I am using angular material, and it worked fine until I tried to sticky header that include colspan and rowspan.I wrote "sticky:true" at each mat-header-row. But I think it may be recalculated cell's height and after that header cell changed as below image.  How can I fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbtwg.png)

My code

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ESTIMATE_DT" [sticky]="true">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="3"> 日期 </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" >
          <a routerLink='/home/patient/nursing-assessment' 
            [queryParams]="{CAPD_NO: row.CAPD_NO, ESTIMATE_DT:row.ESTIMATE_DT}">
            {{row.ESTIMATE_DT}} 
          </a>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      ... //略

      <ng-container matColumnDef="DIALYSIS">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="7">透析液</th>
        <!-- This column doesn't generate <td> items, so no need to add a definition for them -->
      </ng-container>
  
      <ng-container matColumnDef="CA35">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="2">3.5 Ca</th>
        <!-- This column doesn't generate <td> items, so no need to add a definition for them -->
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="CA25">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="2">2.5 ca</th>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="DIALYSIS_15">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> 1.5% L/bag </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.DIALYSIS_15_L}} / {{row.DIALYSIS_15_BAG}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="DIALYSIS_25">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="2"> 2.5% L/bag </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.DIALYSIS_25_L}} / {{row.DIALYSIS_25_BAG}}</td>
      </ng-container>

       ...//略

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['ESTIMATE_DT','WEIGHT','BLOOD_PRESSURE','DIALYSIS'];sticky:true"></tr>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['CA35','CA25','DIALYSIS_11','DIALYSIS_75','UF',];sticky:true"></tr>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['DIALYSIS_15','DIALYSIS_25','DIALYSIS_425';sticky:true"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  
      <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
      <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
        <td class="mat-cell" colspan="48">No data matching the filter</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -2):

I updated the latest version and this problem solved.